# why i can't install surprise in my device

Tags: python, pip, cython, recommendation-engine

I get this error when I try to use `pip install scikit-surprise`:

```
pip install scikit-surprise
Collecting scikit-surprise
  Using cached scikit-surprise-1.1.3.tar.gz (771 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [50 lines of output]
      <string>:65: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
              If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
              ********************************************************************************
      
 
      C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe: No module named pip
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ze6iu_ib\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 101, in _fetch_build_egg_no_warn
          subprocess.check_call(cmd)
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp8dw2sisl', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.17.3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ze6iu_ib\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ze6iu_ib\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ze6iu_ib\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ze6iu_ib\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 65, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ze6iu_ib\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 908, in fetch_build_eggs
          return _fetch_build_eggs(self, requires)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ze6iu_ib\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 38, in _fetch_build_eggs
          resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ze6iu_ib\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
          dist = self._resolve_dist(
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ze6iu_ib\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 865, in _resolve_dist
          dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ze6iu_ib\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1135, in best_match
          return self.obtain(req, installer)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ze6iu_ib\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1147, in obtain
          return installer(requirement)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ze6iu_ib\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 103, in _fetch_build_egg_no_warn
          raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
      distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp8dw2sisl', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.17.3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
PS D:\COC\Scabing\Reco project>
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: The error message says "If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`". What happens if you try that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I managed to fix it in the way described [here](https://github.com/NicolasHug/Surprise/issues/468#issuecomment-1640376222):

```bash
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
python -m pip install --no-use-pep517 scikit-surprise
```

Also note, that a working C++ compiler is required (on Windows Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater).

Note for Linux users: do not forget to install python dev package, e.g. in the case of Fedora you may need to install `python3-devel`

Answer (score -1):

> [**Installation**](https://surpriselib.com)
>
> With pip (you’ll need numpy, and a C compiler. Windows users might prefer using conda): <...>
>
> With conda:

```bash
$ conda install -c conda-forge scikit-surprise
```